# How do I show multiple legends on a VB.Net Chart

Tags: vb.net, charts, legend

My code creates a MS Chart with one or more ChartAreas and I want to have a separate legend for each ChartArea
My code is as below:

```
                For tblNum = 0 To (dsData.Tables.Count - 1)

                tblName = dsData.Tables(tblNum).TableName
                caTag = dtReport.Rows(tblNum).Item("caTag")
                If (dtReport.Rows(tblNum).Item("CAnum") > CAnum) Then
                    CAnum = dtReport.Rows(tblNum).Item("CAnum")
                    myChart.ChartAreas.Add(caTag)
                    myChart.Legends.Add(caTag)
                    With myChart.Legends(caTag)
                        .Docking = Docking.Bottom
                        .DockedToChartArea = caTag
                        .IsDockedInsideChartArea = False
                        .TableStyle = LegendTableStyle.Wide
                        .Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
                        .Enabled = True
                    End With
                    If (caCount > 1) Then
                        CAindex += 1
                        myChart.Titles.Add(caTag)
                        With myChart.Titles(CAindex)
                            .Docking = Docking.Top
                            .DockedToChartArea = caTag
                            .IsDockedInsideChartArea = False
                            .Alignment = ContentAlignment.TopCenter
                            .Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 14, FontStyle.Bold)
                            .Text = caTag
                        End With
                    End If
                Else
                    myChart.Legends(caTag).Enabled = True
                End If
```

However when I run the code only a single Legend is visible containing all series from both ChartAreas as below:
[Legend-1.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwltM.jpg)
Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: As always, ask a question on the forum and you immediately work out the answer

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my own question.
I needed to assign the correct legend to each series as follows:

```
myChart.Series(tblName).Legend = caTag
```

Now both legends are shown with the appropriate series names